# If no records on DAN then use ENU

Tags: sql-server

I really hope you can help me.

I have this table: `Text`

```
Text   | LANGUAGECODE | PRODUCT
BlaENU | ENU          | PROD1
BlaDAN | DAN          | PROD1
BlaENU | ENU          | PROD2
```

I need a SQL line, where I chan check if language code `DAN` exist, then use `DAN`, else USE `ENU`.  How can i do that?

Right now i have lines SQL, but i get both DAN and ENU text out.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Text 
WHERE PRODUCT = 'PROD1' AND (LANGUAGECODE = 'DAN' OR LANGUAGECODE = 'ENU')
```

Can anybody help me with my SQL statement.

Comment: How about a language table with an integer representing its preference that you can join/sort/top 1 by.

Comment: try to use if exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this:

```
SELECT Text, LANGUAGECODE, PRODUCT
FROM (
  SELECT Text, LANGUAGECODE, PRODUCT,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT 
                            ORDER BY CASE 
                                        WHEN LANGUAGECODE='DAN' THEN 1
                                        ELSE 2
                                     END) AS rn
  FROM Text
  WHERE LANGUAGECODE IN ('DAN', 'ENU')) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The `PARTITION BY` clause creates one row-number slice per unique product. The `ORDER BY` clause prioritizes `DAN` code over `ENU`. The outer query picks `DAN` rows where they exist, otherwise it selects `ENU` records.